# Stream video face recognition with video face detection and image face identification

Tags: face-recognition

There are lots of face detection and face recognition(identification) APIs in market. Face detection APIs are for static image or stream video (even offline), but face recognition APIs are mostly for static image.

If I want to build a face recognition service for streaming video, the only thought in my head is combine these two APIs.

With face detection APIs, a trace id is generated each time there is a single face appears in video, no matter whether it's the same one before. So the solution I have is below.

1. detect face in stream video.
2. once there is a new face trace, I will extract several frames (e.g. 0, +1, +2 sec) and crop the face areas.
3. submit these face frames to face recognition API, if they return the same result, that's the one in video.

Whether it's the most effective way with existing APIs?

Answer (score 1):

You can lean on this CodeProject-Article for realtime Face-Dedection & Recognition:

[Multiple face detection and recognition in real time](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/239849/Multiple-face-detection-and-recognition-in-real)

It uses the [EigenFace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenface) algorithm to recognize and dedect multibe faces.